# How to print json data from url to excel?

Tags: python, json, parsing, csv, url

```
import urllib 
import json
import re
import csv
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

game_code = open("/Users//Desktop/PYTHON/gc.txt").read()

game_code = game_code.split("\r")


for gc in game_code:

    htmltext =urllib.urlopen("http://cluster.leaguestat.com/feed/index.php?feed=gc&key=f109cf290fcf50d4&client_code=ohl&game_id="+gc+"&lang_code=en&fmt=json&tab=pxpverbose")

    soup= BeautifulSoup(htmltext, "html.parser")
    j= json.loads(soup.text)
    summary = ['GC'],['Pxpverbose']
    for event in summary:
        print gc, ["event"]
```

I can not seem to access the lib to print the proper headers and row. I ultimately want to export specific rows to csv. I downloaded python 2 days ago, so i am very new. I needed this one data set for a project. Any advice or direction would be greatly appreciated.

Here are a few game codes if anyone wanted to take a look. Thanks

21127,20788,20922,20752,21094,21196,21295,21159,21128,20854,21057

Answer (score 1):

Here are a few thoughts:

- I'd like to point out the excellent [`requests`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/v0.10.7/) as an alternative to  urllib for all your HTTP needs in Python (you may need to `pip install requests`).
- `requests` comes with a built-in json decoder (you don't need BeautifulSoup).
- In fact, you have already imported a great module ([`csv`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html)) to print headers and rows of data.  You can also use this module to write the data to a file.
- Your data is returned as a dictionary ([`dict`](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries)) in Python, a data structure indexed by *keys*.  You can access the *values* (I think this is what you mean by "specific rows") in your data with these keys.

One of many possible ways to accomplish what you want:

```
import requests
import csv

game_code = open("/Users//Desktop/PYTHON/gc.txt").read()
game_code = game_code.split("\r")

for gc in game_code:
    r = requests.get("http://cluster.leaguestat.com/feed/index.php?feed=gc&key=f109cf290fcf50d4&client_code=ohl&game_id="+gc+"&lang_code=en&fmt=json&tab=pxpverbose")
    data = r.json()

    with open("my_data.csv", "a") as csvfile:
        wr = csv.writer(csvfile,delimiter=',')
        for summary in data["GC"]["Pxpverbose"]:
            wr.writerow([gc,summary["event"]])
            # add keys to write additional values;
            # e.g. summary["some-key"].  Example: 
            # wr.writerow([gc,summary["event"],summary["id"]])
```

Comment: Thank you! @Daniel What would be the best way to add on additional keys?

Comment: My pleasure!  Added comments to my answer; happy to clarify if it doesn't make sense.

Comment: That means that you are trying to reference a key that doesn't exist in each "summary" dictionary.  Without going down a rabbit hole here in the comments, you might look at error handling: https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions.  A little advanced if you're just starting out in Python, but that's the right direction.  The idea would be: `try: wr.writerow([gc,summary["event"],summary["some-key-that-doesn't-exist"]]) except KeyError: #do something with the error`

Comment: My pleasure!  Since you are new to Stackoverflow, the best way to say "thanks" is to accept and up-vote the answer: http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You don't need beautiful soup for this; the data can be read directly from the URL into JSON format.

```
import urllib, json
response = urllib.urlopen("http://cluster.leaguestat.com/feed/index.php?feed=gc&key=f109cf290fcf50d4&client_code=ohl&game_id=" + gc +"&lang_code=en&fmt=json&tab=pxpverbose")
data = json.loads(response.read())
```

At this point, `data` is the parsed JSON of your web page.

Excel can read csv files, so easiest route would be exporting the data you want into a CSV file using [this](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) library.

This should be enough to get you started. Modify `fieldnames` to include specific event details in the columns of the csv file.

```
import csv

with open('my_games.csv', 'w') as csvfile:
    fieldnames = ['event', 'id']
    writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=fieldnames,
                            extrasaction='ignore')
    writer.writeheader()
    for event in data['GC']['Pxpverbose']:
        writer.writerow(event)
```

Comment: Thank you for the help. Still prints out as a blank .csv with just header names. It seems to be having trouble locating the dictionary keys of the actual data I want.

Comment: @denn9268 whoops, looked like the code had a couple bugs. Should give you a CSV file containing a columns of event and ID now.

Comment: I am getting error "return self.writer.writerow(self._dict_to_list(rowdict))"